# Facebook Graph API - Getting an access token that never expires

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get a copy of my status updates on my website homepage using the Graph API, but I'm struggling to get an access code that works at all, let alone one that never expires.

I'm using the Explorer and sometimes I get an access code that works but mostly I get the following:

[image]

Any ideas what I need to do? I'm guessing I need to play around with the settings.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension

Comment: @CBroe I've looked at this and still can't get it to work. I don't want to have to get a user access code at all... It's a public page so I just want to display the feed.

Comment: Then use your app access token. (The combination of app_id|app_secret, with a pipe symbol in the middle, always works as an app access token, and doesn’t expire.) You need to replace `me` with the actual page id in that case.

Comment: @CBroe - That's got it... I hadn't replaced 'me' with the page id... easy when you know how. Thanks for guiding me with this. You've saved a whole lot of frustration. Much appreciated.